# Why hard-coded dates in WHERE clause gives faster performance then same dates as a parameters?

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql, database-administration

Why such a huge difference in performance if I put my dates in WHERE clause (first query)  or if I put same dates as a parameters (second query)

```
--------/* Execution time 3 sec*/ 
   select 
            tblNoteDiaries.DueDate,
            col2,
            col3
    from MyTable 
    where CAST(tblNoteDiaries.DueDate as date) <= cast(getdate()as date) and cast( tblNoteDiaries.DueDate as date) >= CAST('2017-09-29' as DATE)

--------/* Execution time 10 sec*/    
    declare     @DateFrom datetime = '2017-09-29',
                @DateTo datetime = '2017-10-05'
    select 
            tblNoteDiaries.DueDate,
            col2,
            col3
    from    MyTable 
    where   CAST(tblNoteDiaries.DueDate as date)  >= @DateFrom   and cast( tblNoteDiaries.DueDate as date) <= @DateTo
```

I need this query as a stored procedure, what would be the best approach to utilize date parameters without degrading performance??

Comment: do you see any difference in execution plan?

Comment: Most likely parameter sniffing. The execution plan will give you a clue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I simulated on my database using below queries

```
select sum(PrinBal)
from fpc
where SnapshotDt >= '2017-06-01' and SnapshotDt <= '2017-06-30'
go

declare @sd date = '2017-06-01'
declare @ed date = '2017-06-30'
select sum(PrinBal)
from fpc
where SnapshotDt >= @sd and SnapshotDt <= @ed
go
```

and checked execution plan. it was 48% for first query and 52% for the second one.

Then I added `option(recompile)` to the second query and then both took exact the same percentage

```
declare @sd date = '2017-06-01'
declare @ed date = '2017-06-30'
select sum(PrinBal)
from fpc
where SnapshotDt >= @sd and SnapshotDt <= @ed
option(recompile)
go
```

So as Nick, said, it is parameter sniffing.

You can get rid of parameter sniffing using updated statistics or using `RECOMPILE` option for your queries and stored procedures.

Answer (score 0):

Because your variables are declared as `datetime`. This has a higher data type precedence. So you're converting your `DueDate` column to `date` explicitly, and then converting again to `datetime`.

Use `date` for your variables, and you should see the same performance. Even better, don't `CAST` your date column if the type is already correct.

Comment: I tested with both date and datetime types but don't see any difference.